# Newtonsoft.Json trying to guess token type and getting it wrong

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to change how the Newtonsoft serializer deals with strings like "2017-05-27".

So, I created a class to be used instead of DateTime, a converter for that type and hoped it would be it.

The problem is, for "2017-05-27" it works indeed. But if, for some reason, I get "2017-05-27T23:50:27:00", i.e. a complete ISO 8601 string, the JsonReader pretends to be intelligent and treats this as a DateTime instead of a string.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

The code I've done so far is this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConverterGames
{
    public class MyDate
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Day { get; set; }
    }
    public class Xxx
    {
        public MyDate Aaa { get; set; }
    }

    public class DateJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        private readonly Regex _isoDate = new Regex(@"^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+).*", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // gives "string" for 2017-04-27 :-)
            // gives DateTime for 2017-04-27T20:00:00.00 :-(
            // I want string only here.
            Console.WriteLine(reader.Value.GetType());

            Match m = _isoDate.Match((string)reader.Value);
            if (!m.Success)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Format error for {(string)reader.Value}");
            }
            return new MyDate
            {
                Year = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value),
                Month = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value),
                Day = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[3].Value),
            };
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(MyDate);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string Data = "{\"aaa\":\"2017-05-12\"}";
            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.Converters.Add(new DateJsonConverter());

            // good
            Xxx x= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Xxx>(Data, settings);
            Console.WriteLine(x.Aaa.Year);


            // fails
            Data = "{\"aaa\":\"2017-05-12T08:15:00\"}";
            x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Xxx>(Data, settings);
            Console.WriteLine(x.Aaa.Year);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Since you are going to handle the date parsing yourself, you just need to set `DateParseHandling` to `None` in the serializer settings:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
settings.Converters.Add(new DateJsonConverter());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3WSj6Q

Comment: Ok, got it. setting DateParseHandling to none just forces the parsing into the parser instead of the lexer and then my converter gets a chance to deal with it correctly. Thanks!